# using T hotelling output in R

Tags: r

I have 4 statistics such as : weight, height, temp, purity. And i want to apply t^2 hotelling for them. 
**First**, is it right if i run :

```
HotellingsT2(MatrixOfVariables)matrix(c(weight, height, temp, purity),nrow=4,ncol=1)
```

for getting t^2 hotelling test for these statistics?

**Second**,Output gets all elements of t^2 hotelling test.What should i do,If i just want to get "t^2 hotelling statistic" from  HotellingsT2(X, ...)? 
(I mean i want to get just 3.7648 for output.)

```
MatrixOfVariables <-matrix(c(weight, height, temp, purity),nrow=4,ncol=1)
output <- HotellingsT2(MatrixOfVariables)
output

#Hotelling's one sample T2-test
data:  MatrixOfVariables
T.2 = 3.7648, df1 = 1, df2 = 3, p-value = 0.1477
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to c(0)
```